# UPDATE statement with subselect

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I created a script with the necessary condition for me. And it works properly. **But I have a need to apply this script on many rows**. And not only where id is `15`.

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_field =
  (SELECT 
     CASE WHEN position('a' in my_field) = 0 THEN my_field
          WHEN position('a' in my_field) = 1 THEN substring(my_field from 1 for 5)
          WHEN position('a' in my_field) > 1 THEN substring(my_field from 2 for 5)
     END 
   FROM my_table WHERE id = 15)
WHERE id = 15
```

I would like to apply this script on rows where specific condition performs.
For example I would like to write `WHERE my_field LIKE '%ab%'`. **But the problem is that I have subselect**. So I can apply separate script to get all the necessary id and then apply this script manually substituting the individual id from separate script. But I want to apply it automatically with a single query.

Comment: So, you want to get a list of ID's and loop over the list replacing the ID with the current one in the loop, for example?

Comment: I started writing the code in T-SQL, then realised you were using postgresql, so this code will not be useful - so take a look at this link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: To be precise I want to get a list of rows and apply this script automatically for these specific rows. Explicit loop is not necessary if I can do without it.

Comment: In other words I want `UPDATE my_table SET my_field = 3 WHERE my_field LIKE '%ab%'`. But I have specific logic for setting value `my_field` instead `my_field = 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than you think :)

Try this:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_field =
    CASE
          WHEN position('a' in my_field) = 0 THEN my_field
          WHEN position('a' in my_field) = 1 THEN substring(my_field from 1 for 5)
          WHEN position('a' in my_field) > 1 THEN substring(my_field from 2 for 5)
    END
```